# What does `<attribute 'xxx' of 'C' objects>` mean in the output of `C.__dict__`?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-internals

```
>>> class C:
...     pass
... 
>>> C.__dict__
mappingproxy({'__doc__': None, 
'__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'C' objects>, 
'__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'C' objects>, 
'__module__': '__main__'})
```

In `<attribute 'xxx' of 'C' objects>`,

- does `'C' objects` mean instances of `C`?
- does `<attribute 'xxx' of 'C' objects>` mean `xxx` is an attribute of instances of `C`? But it is listed by `C.__dict__` as an attribute of `C`.

Why are some attributes ( e.g. `__doc__` and `__module__`) of `C` not mentioned with `<attribute 'xxx' of 'C' objects>`, while others are?

---

**Re: "note: `<attribute ..>` is basically the repr of these descriptors"**

Why is `<attribute ..>` not shown in the following example?

```
>>> class md:
...     def __get__(self, obj, owner):
...         return 3
... 

>>> class CC:
...     d=md()
... 
>>> CC.__dict__
mappingproxy({'d': <__main__.md object at 0x7f7387f8c978>, ...})
```

Comment: this question is even more interesting if you consider the output of `C.__class__.__dict__`

Comment: I've noticed @Tim that that you often add a salutatory remark to your question. While this is certainly consider polite when speaking with someone face to face, it only adds noise to posts on Stack Overflow. Please see [_Why are fellow users removing thank-you's from my questions?_](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328379/why-are-fellow-users-removing-thank-yous-from-my-questions) for further details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are [`PyGetSetDescrObject`s](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/11045c9d8a21dd9bd182a3939189db02815f9783/Objects/descrobject.c#L650) which are computed attributes (descriptors implemented in C) for instances of the class `C`. [Documentation on these](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/descriptor.html#descriptor-objects) is minimal (or I can't seem to find it :-), but, you can take a look at [`tp_getset` in the `C-API`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/typeobj.html#c.PyTypeObject.tp_getset) that talks a bit about these:

> `struct PyGetSetDef* PyTypeObject.tp_getset`
>
> An optional pointer to a static NULL-terminated array of PyGetSetDef structures, *declaring computed attributes of instances of this type*.
>
> For each entry in the array, an entry is added to the type’s dictionary (see tp_dict below) containing a getset descriptor.

The objects that *don't have* `<attribute ..>` (note: `<attribute ..>` is basically the `repr` of these descriptors) are simply not descriptors (`__doc__` is usually a string or `None` if not defined while `__module__` holds the name of the module in which the class was defined).

---

> Re: "note: `<attribute ..>` is basically the repr of these descriptors"
>
> Why is `<attribute ..>` not shown in the following example?

To address this update that I missed.

Because that's a descriptor implemented in Python and inherits the default `repr` from `object`.

The `repr` function of the `PyGetSetDescrObject`s implemented in `C` uses a different `repr`, mainly in order to distinguish them (I'd assume).

Comment: Thanks. "note: `<attribute ..>` is basically the repr of these descriptors".

Why is `<attribute ..>` not shown in an example which I updated to my post?

Comment: @Tim I just noticed the update, sorry for that. I've updated my answer to expand on your question.